# Drawing pixels on the screen with SDL in C

Tags: c, sdl

I have a project in which i need to draw pixels on the screen with SDL. A bit of code has been supplied to me:

```
int render_screen(SDL_Surface* screen)
{
  pixel pixel_white;
  pixel_white.r = (Uint8)0xff;
  pixel_white.g = (Uint8)0xff;
  pixel_white.b = (Uint8)0xff;
  pixel_white.alpha = (Uint8)128;


  SDL_LockSurface(screen);
  /*do your rendering here*/


  /*----------------------*/
  SDL_UnlockSurface(screen);

  /*flip buffers*/
  SDL_Flip(screen);
  clear_screen(screen);

  return 0;
}
```

Also this function:

```
void put_pixel(SDL_Surface* screen,int x,int y,pixel* p)
{
  Uint32* p_screen = (Uint32*)screen->pixels;
  p_screen += y*screen->w+x;
  *p_screen = SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format,p->r,p->g,p->b,p->alpha);  
}
```

There is a number of things in this code that i don't really understand. First, i assume the idea is that i should call the function put_pixel from within the render_screen function, but with what arguments? The put_pixel(SDL_Surface* screen,int x,int y,pixel* p) line seems complicated. If x and y is the function draw arguments, why are they then declared in the function indata? I should have to call put_pixel with the command put_pixel(something,x,y,something2). If i use say x=56 and y= 567, aren't they resetted to 0 when declared in the parentesis? And what should i put in something and something2 to make it work?

Comment: I think the real issue here is that you are a beginner to C.  C is a challenging language to learn at first.  If you want to get started with writing games, you'll probably have more success with PyGame or Löve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixel-drawing in SDL2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20579658/pixel-drawing-in-sdl2-0)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SDL_LockSurface(screen);
put_pixel(screen,56,567,&pixel_white);
SDL_UnlockSurface(screen);
```

And as it has been mentioned , maybe take the time to learn a bit more the  C language. particularly, taking into account your question,  you may focus on function arguments and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

the formal parameter`SDL_Surface *screen` is simply a pointer to an SDL_Surface structure, in your case you are likely concerned with the one returned by `SDL_SetVideoMode()`.

`pixel *p` is a pointer to a struct of type pixel, as below.

```
typedef struct {
    Uint8 r;
    Uint8 g;
    Uint8 b;
    Uint8 alpha;
} pixel;
```

instead of using screen->w, it's suggested to calculate an offset in bytes from the base pointer using pitch, which is the length of the surface's scanline in bytes.

instead of

```
    Uint32* p_screen = (Uint32*)screen->pixels;
    p_screen += y*screen->w+x;
    *p_screen = SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format,p->r,p->g,p->b,p->alpha);
```

try using:

```
    /* Get a pointer to the video surface's pixels in memory. */
    Uint32 *pixels = (Uint32*) screen->pixels;

    /* Calculate offset to the location we wish to write to */
    int offset = (screen->pitch / sizeof(Uint32)) * y + x;

    /* Compose RGBA values into correct format for video surface and copy to screen */
    *(pixels + offset) = SDL_MapRGBA(screen->format, p->r, p->g, p->b, p->alpha);
```